# Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The element has no supported sources

Tags: javascript, angularjs, audio, d3.js

Using music-frequency-d3 for audio visualization in my AngularJs application, created a bower component for this using music-frequency-d3,
but when I insert the web address of my audio as src attribute's value it shows the error below.

Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The element has no supported sources

what is the problem here? how can I play the audio using the web address URL?

Thank You

Comment: solved it,its the cors access restriction issue.

Answer (score 6):

Its the cors access restriction issue

add

```html
crossOrigin="anonymous"
```

inside your audio tag

```html
<audio media-player="audioPlayer" autoplay controls="controls" preload="auto" id="audioElement"
                crossOrigin="anonymous" src="{{audio}}"></audio>
```

Comment: Worked B4.. it'll work again..

Comment: How to do it when working with `new Audio` object in `js` code?